# Angular application name not identified

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

I'm trying to define a factory for DB access using the following sample code:

```
    MyApp.service("DB_Services", [ "$http" , function($http) {

        DB_Services.Get_Data_from_DB_Internal = function (p_Request) {

            var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url  = "http://localhost/servlet/Test_ui";
            var params = "data=" + p_Request ;
            http.open("POST", url, true);

            //Send the proper header information along with the request
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                    return http.responseText ;
                }
        }
        http.send(params);    
        

        return DB_Services ;
    }]);
```

I should add that this piece of code is deployed in a separate file which is listed in a `<script src=...>` entry within the index.html.

Upon loading (and before any use of it!), I get the following error (Chorme's console): Uncaught ReferenceError: MyApp is not defined.

Of course, MyApp is the very same name used throughout all controllers, so there is no spelling error.

Moreover, if I change "MyApp" to something else, say, "TestName", I get the same error except that this time what is not defined is TestName.

I cannot figure out what the syntax error is.

Comment: How do you reference to your module name through MyApp ? `MyApp = angular.module('myApp')` ? And how the `MyApp`'s scope is set ?

Comment: Where is `MyApp` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer is based on the assumption you are bootstrapping your angular app (e.g. `angular.module('myApp')`) in a separate `<script>` file in your index.html*

#### check the order of your `<script>` files

You need to ensure that your initial angular setup code appears before any other angular `<script>`s.

```
<head>
    .....
    <script>
         var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
    </script>

    <script src="otherNg.js">
    <script src="anotherNg.js">
```

#### be sure to reference your module in other `<script>` files properly

In order to properly add additional constructs to your `myApp` module, you need to be sure to access it properly.  Since it was defined in another file, you need to use the following syntax to gain access to it:

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp')
 .service("DB_Services", [ .... ])
```

Note that this code doesn't include the 2nd parameter of the array... this is because this is *getter* syntax for getting already defined modules.

Comment: Yes!!! Changing the location of the factory declaration within the `index.html` made the trick. Now, I have a different issue: when invoking the function as `blabla = DB_Services.Get_Data_from_DB_Internal ("dummy");` I get the error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'Get_Data_from_DB_Internal' of undefined**. Tried different syntaxes without success.

Comment: That sounds like an injection issue.  Assuming you're consuming your `DB_Services` inside a controller, you need to be sure to add it as a injectable dependency to the controller function's arguments.  BTW if this answer resolved the initial problem, please consider marking it as the correct one.  You can file a separate question for the injection issue as it is out of scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to reference the module in your script file

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp');
MyApp.service(...);
```

This is different from when you define the module initially

```
angular.module('MyApp',[]);
```

From experience this is not dependent on the order of the script files in your .html, for example:

```
<script src="javascripts/services/DB_Services.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>
```

This will work just fine as long as you reference the module in your DB_Services.js script. angular will do the math!