# Invocation of Factory function triggers error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular application where DB access is managed through a single function within a factory. The factory declaration is:

```
var MayApp = angular.module('MayApp'); 

MayApp.factory("DB_Services", [ "$http" , function($http) {

    var This_Factory = {} ;

    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

    This_Factory.Get_Data_from_DB_Internal = function (p_Request) {

        var http    = new XMLHttpRequest()  ;
        var url     = MyURL                 ;
        var params  = "data=" + p_Request   ;
        http.open("POST", url, true);

        //Send the proper header information along with the request
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                return http.responseText ;
            }
        }
        http.send(params);    
    }    

    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

    This_Factory.Get_Data_from_DB = function Get_Data_from_DB($scope, DB_Services) {
        var myDataPromise = DB_Services.Get_Data_from_DB_Internal("Dummy");
        myDataPromise.then(function(result) {
            return result ;
        });
    }
    return This_Factory ;
}]);
```

The controller using this service looks as follows:

```
MayApp.controller('MyController' , ['$scope' , 'DB_Services' , function( $scope , DB_Services) {

    $scope.Search_Lookups = function () {

        var l_Lookup_Type = document.getElementById("Lookup_Seed").value ;

        var l_Data = MyApp.DB_Services.Get_Data_from_DB(l_Lookup_Type);

        console.log ("Received response: " + l_Data) ;

        return l_Data ;

    }

} ]) ;
```

The function `Search_Lookups` is invoked when clicking on a button. The generated error message is: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Get_Data_from_DB' of undefined`.

I had [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748036/angular-application-name-not-identified/34748590?noredirect=1#comment57288873_34748590) with this factory and were resolved by changing the location of its inclusion (i.e. `<script src="Private_Libs/Factories/DB_Services.js"></script>`) within the index.html file. Now, I get no errors when loading the page, but still the `Get_Data_from_DB` is not seen by the controller.

Any clue for the reason?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing your own XMLHttpRequest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have injected the factory into your controller under the name of `DB_Services`. When you want to call it you simply use `DB_Services`, not `MayApp.DB_Services`, the factory is not a method of your app, it's a standalone variable in your controller which you defined when injecting it.

Also the way you're handling your request, I think it's not gonna work, you should pass a promise back from the factory not the value retrieved after your promise is resolved, because your controller assigns `l_data` to undefined instantly after you call the factory function, and will not wait for the factory's promise to resolve.

Comment: Hey @SinaGh!!! Your suggestion for the first point did the job. As for the second... studying.... Thanks for your quick fix.

Comment: @FDavidov Happy you took my suggestion to heart :)

Comment: Dear @SinaGh, in the past days I **learned** that your words should always be taken seriously and, though I lack a lot of knowledge, I am a quick learner! :-). BTW, I solved the second point too, so now I have a nice access to the DB.